# readdirSync() doesn't find any file

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

My problem is the follow:
readdirSync() doesn't find any file inside the folder even if they exists and it doesn't fire any error.
Here's the code, thank you very much for your patience, I'm pretty new to electron js.

```
function libraryPath(packetDir) {
var libraryPath = "";
fs.readdirSync(packetDir+"\\bin", function (err,files) {
    for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        console.log(packetDir+"\\"+files[i]);
        libraryPath += packetDir+"\\"+files[i];
    }
});
return libraryPath; }
```

Comment: But readdirSync shouldn't be asynchronous and so the entire function. Am I wrong?

Comment: Which file system are you using?

Comment: The standard fs module. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system

Comment: I meant Windows, Linux, Mac... You might be getting an error with the `\\\` notation.  OSes have variable syntax.

Comment: Windows. It seems that the function readdirsync doesn't find any file even if they exist... I'll update the thread title, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a callback to a 'Sync'rounous function. You'll notice in the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdirsync_path_options) that there is no `callback` parameter to the Sync version only in the async version which does not end with 'sync'

So to get what you want, call like a regular, non callback style, function.

```
var files = fs.readdirSync(packetDir+"\\bin");

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    console.log(packetDir+"\\"+files[i]);
    libraryPath += packetDir+"\\"+files[i];
}
```